# No variables defined in jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, foreach, send

I normally use javascript ajax and everything works fine, but wordpress requires jquery ajax which i am not familiar with.

Why are the variables described in the following code are not defined?

```
var option = "'USER_ID': 'my id is 32',"
var note = "'this is my first note'";

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
             option   //this does not work. <--- WHAT DO YOU MEAN DOES NOT WORK?
            'USER_NOTE': note  //this does not work. <--- WHAT DO YOU MEAN DOES NOT WORK?
            
        };

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi can you show `divsname` html ?

Comment: var divsname = document.getElementById("userid");

Comment: `divsname` is id ? then why do you need to use forEach ?

Comment: That part is not important, put what you want, the problem is that I can't put any variables in data ajax to send

Comment: var divsname = document.getElementById("userid").getAttribute("class");

Comment: If your problem is that the variables are undefined inside the jQuery ready function, then it's probably a scoping issue in which case my answers should solve that. If you problem is that your jQuery post is causing an exception, then Flash Thunder's answer addresses that.

Comment: @geoidesic in fact I guess it's not true :) when you var in main scope, the variable is available in every inner scope, there is no way that `.ready` event would get triggered before the main code flow, so I guess it should work (not counting the error from my answer)

Comment: Question is also missing much punctuation. There's a semicolon missing after the first line and a comma missing after `option` in `data` definition – these will also cause errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a codepen with your question: https://codepen.io/geoidesic/pen/wvoEdeN

Here is the code:

```
var option = "'USER_ID': 'my id is 32',";
var USER_ID = 'my id is 32';
var note = "'this is my first note'";


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log(option); // proves that option is in scope
  console.log(note); // proves that option is in scope
  var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
             USER_ID,
            'USER_NOTE': note
        };
  console.log(data); // proves that data is working

  jQuery.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', data, (response) => {
    console.log('response: ',response);
  })
});
```

If you view the console. You can see that there is no problem with any undefined variables. If you view the network tab you can see that the POST request is sent.

This should also serve as an example of how better to formulate your questions in a way in which people can actually help you, i.e. by using CodePen or similar.

Comment: True .., strangely enough, then something wordpress filters, so I can't get values.., hm

Comment: I think this answers the question. Perhaps mark it as the accepted answer and ask a new question once you figure out what to ask. Also I'd suggest that you read through my edit of your question and clarify it as per my capitalised inline comments.

Comment: I'm just reviewing the code on the codepen: Network - Preview shows that (option: "'USER_ID': 'my id is 32',")..., this should not be under "option", it would be correct (USER_ID: 'my id is 32' ,)

Comment: @maja then why did you assign it to option? I've updated it for you as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `data` json object is not properly defined. You need to change your option definition to the valid json object:

```
var option = "'USER_ID': 'my id is 32',"
```

to

```
var option = {'USER_ID': 'my id is 32'}
```

And add it a bit different way, so it would get merged properly:

```
var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        ...option,                    
        'USER_NOTE': note           
        
    };
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question that was asked, however it may well be the solution to the OP's actual problem.

Comment: Ok, now, it's being sent but I'm not getting any value USER_ID is empty, why?

Comment: even when you are defining it exactly like that ? `{'USER_ID': 'my id is 32'}` ? it is empty or undefined? what exactly does the response contain? use `console.log(response)` instead of alert. And check that in browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just move everything into jQuery.ready

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    var option = "'USER_ID': 'my id is 32',"
    var note = "this is my first note";

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        option,                    
        'USER_NOTE': note           
        
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Not a single example of mine works, Let's forget aboutEach. How to insert a user_id variable into data as if it does not exist for Each?

Comment: You English isn't great. I don't know what you mean. I suggest you create a jsFiddle or CodePen example of what you are trying to do, then it's easier to help. It's not a well formulated question if you're having to say "forget about x, y, or z" in the comments. You need to simplify. At the moment you are trying to ask several questions in one question and you're getting nowhere. Your question doesn't even make sense "What is the best way to insert for Each variable in the data in jQuery Ajax" –– this doesn't mean anything. There is no such thing as a "for Each variable" and u say to ignore it

Comment: I've modified the question completely, so let's go step by step (I hope it doesn't go against the rules of the site)

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answers to match your question. Both answers still apply. Have you actually tried my suggestions?

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't send anything, I'll try the Flash Thunder code, I'll let you know

Comment: Why have you given 3 separate answers? Just put it all in one.

Answer (score -1):

Define it as a function and wrap it in a closure passing the context in.

```
var option = "'USER_ID': 'my id is 32',"
var note = "this is my first note";
const process = (function() {
  const data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    option
    'USER_NOTE': note
  }
  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
  });
})(option, note)

jQuery(document).ready(process);
```